# How to get AFNetworking authentication header in a scripting language like PHP?

Tags: php, afnetworking

I have :

```
  [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:userNameOrEmail password:password];
```

How do I get these values if posted to a PHP application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFNetworking uses **HTTP basic authentication** is this case. You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` to get the username and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` for the password.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 1):

When sending the request, it seemingly uses `Authentication` HTTP header. In PHP however, to get headers, you perform this call:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
```

You need to get the entry associated with `Authentication` key. To make PHP code fully standards-compliant, you would need to do something like that, to match header in case-insensitive manner:

```
$auth = null;
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    if (strtolower($name) === 'authentication') {
        $auth = $value;
        break;
    };
};
// if $auth === null, the header was not set
```

In general, I suppose using `getallheaders()` will help you answer all questions you will soon have about what AFNetworking sends to your script in the headers :)

More reading:

- [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php),
- [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php),